# Prove the inequality knowing $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $xyz=1$ $\frac{x^5}{x^2+1}+\frac{y^5}{y^2+1}+\frac{z^5}{z^2+1}\ge\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove the inequality knowing $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $xyz=1$ $$\frac{x^5}{x^2+1}+\frac{y^5}{y^2+1}+\frac{z^5}{z^2+1}\ge\frac{3}{2}$$

Starting from the condition set that $xyz =1$ I did this :
$$x^3+y^3+z^3\ge3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3z^3}$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3\ge3$$
I also know that the fraction $\frac{3}{2}$ usually either comes from the famous $Nesbitt$ equation or from some sort of $Tittu$ that leads to $\frac{9}{4}$ which then is simplified.

However I can't find any way how to manipulate the inequality. I did try to multiply and rewrite the inequality so that $x,y,z$ are an even power like this :
$$\frac{x^4}{x^2+yz}+\frac{y^4}{y^2+xz}+\frac{z^4}{z^2+xy}\ge\frac{3}{2}$$

However this didn't bring me anywhere. Any kind of help is welcomed.

Comment: As further practice, try to solve $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^5}{x^3+1} \ge 1.5$ given $xyz=1$.

Answer (score 6):

We use the **tangent line method**, ie first set $f(x)= \frac{x^5}{x^2+1}$ so that we have to show that $$f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \geq \frac{3}{2}$$

Note $f’’(x) \geq 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. Considering the tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=1$, it becomes clear that $f(x) \geq 2x-\frac{3}{2}$ (try to verify this by cross multiplication) so that $$f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \geq 2(x+y+z) - \frac{9}{2} \geq 6-\frac{9}{2} = \frac32$$ where the last inequality follows via AM-GM. Equality is attained at $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{x^5}{x^2 +1} = \frac{4x^3-1}{6} +\underbrace{ \frac{(x-1)^2(2x^3+4x^2+2x+1)}{6(x^2+1)}}_{\ge0} \ge \frac{4x^3-1}{6}$$
Then
$$\sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{x^5}{x^2 +1} \ge \sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{4x^3-1}{6} = -\frac{1}{2} + \underbrace{\frac{2}{3}\sum_{\text{sym}}x^3}_{\ge 2xyz = 2} \ge \frac{3}{2}$$

The equality occurs if and only if $x = y= z= 1$

Comment: (+1)How did you get the factorization though?

Comment: @DS I guessed that we can decompose $x^5$ to a form like 
$$x^5 = (x^2 +1)(ax^3 +bx^2 + cx +d )  + (x-1)^2 (ex^3 +f x^2 + g x + h)$$
because the equality occurs when $x = 1$
Then I solve for $(a,b,c,d,...)$. Luckily it works ;) (that is $e,f,g,h$ are all positive)

Comment: Thank you @NN2 .

Comment: @DS Your solution is nice also, I'm looking at it

Comment: Side note: This is "equivalent" to the tangent line, which gives us $ x^5 / (x^2 + 1)   - (2x - 3/2) = ( x-1)^2 ( 2x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x + 3 ) / [ 2 ( x^2 + 1) ] $.  $\quad$ where it starts to get interesting, is when the tangent line doesn't work at the extremes, but we can manipulate it with $A (x-1)^2$ to get another expression.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't think so. The two solutions are not equivalent and mine is stronger. In fact, my "remainder formula" is $(4x^3-1)/6$ of degree $x^3$ while with tangent line method, the remainder formula is of degree $x^1$. So, my solution is stronger in the sense that, if we change to a weaker condition such that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 3$, my solution still works while the tangent line method fails.

Comment: Agreed, equivalent wasn't the right word I was looking for, which is why I put the quotation marks. To refine my comment, what I meant is that they use the similar idea of  $ x^5/(x^2+1) = f(x) + g(x) ( x-1)^2$, where $g(x)  \geq 0$ in the domain, whence $\sum x^5/(x^2+1) \geq \sum f(x)$.   $\quad$ EG Taking the difference of these $f(x)$, we get $(4x^3 - )/ 6 - (2x-3/2) = 2(x-1)^2(x+2) /3$ (a multiple of $(x-1)^2$ as expected).  $\quad$ Of course, there's a question of how much more $(x-1)^2$ we can pull out to get stronger statements.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach:
We try to homogenize the inequality. Let $(xyz)^{2/3}$ be denoted by $p$.
$$\begin{align} \sum_{cyc} \frac{x^5}{x^2+1} &= \sum_{cyc}\frac{x^5}{x^2+p} \\
&= \frac1{xyz}\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^5}{x^2+p} \\
&\ge \frac 3{x^3+y^3+z^3} \sum_{cyc}\frac{x^6}{x^3+xp} \tag{AM-GM} \\
&\ge \frac 3{\sum_{cyc} x^3} \frac{\left(\sum_{cyc} x^3\right)^2}{\sum_{cyc} x^3+xp} \tag{C-S} \\
&= 3\cdot \frac{\sum_{cyc} x^3}{\sum_{cyc} x^3+xp} \ge \frac{3}{2}
\end{align}$$
where the last inequality follows since $$\sum_{cyc}x^3 \ge \sum_{cyc} xp$$which is trivially true by Muirhead or AM-GM.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: $$\sum \frac{x^5}{x^2+1} =\frac{1}{(xyz)^{2/3}}\cdot \sum \frac{x^5}{x^2+xyz} =$$

$$= \frac{1}{(xyz)^{2/3}}\cdot \sum \frac{x^4}{x+yz} \overset{\text{AM-GM}}\ge \frac{3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\cdot\sum \frac{(x^2)^2}{x+yz} \ge $$

$$\overset{\text{Titu}}\ge \frac{3}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\cdot \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{xy+yz+zx+x+y+z}\ge $$

$$\overset{*}\ge \frac{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{x^2+y^2+z^2+x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac32.$$

$(*)$ is true because $$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+zx$$ and $$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge x+y+z$$ which follows from

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{3} \ge (x+y+z)\sqrt[3]{xyz}=x+y+z.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since we have the constraint $xyz = 1$, we can make the substitution $x = 
\frac{a}{b}$, $y = \frac{b}{c}$, and $z = \frac{c}{a}$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive real numbers. (If you haven't seen this before, you can for example let $a = x$, $b = 1$, and $c = \frac{1}{y}$, but we aren't really interested in the particular values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.)

We then want to prove that the inequality
$$
  \frac{a^5}{a^2 b^3 + b^5} + \frac{b^5}{b^2 c^3 + c^5} + \frac{c^5}{c^2 a^3 + a^5} \geq \frac{3}{2}
$$
holds for all positive real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ (without any additional constraints) or, equivalently,
$$
  \frac{a^6}{a^3 b^3 + a b^5} + \frac{b^6}{b^3 c^3 + b c^5} + \frac{c^6}{c^3 a^3 + c a^5} \geq \frac{3}{2}.
$$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (sometimes called Titu's Lemma, like in your question)
$$
  \frac{a^6}{a^3 b^3 + a b^5} + \frac{b^6}{b^3 c^3 + b c^5} + \frac{c^6}{c^3 a^3 + c a^5} \geq \frac{(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)^2}{a^3 b^3 + b^3 c^3 + c^3 a^3 + ab^5 + bc^5 + ca^5},
$$
so it is enough to show that
$$
  2a^6 + 2b^6 + 2c^6 + 4a^3 b^3 + 4b^3 c^3 + 4c^3 a^3 \geq 3a^3 b^3 + 3b^3 c^3 + 3c^3 a^3 + 3ab^5 + 3bc^5 + 3ca^5,
$$
or more simply
$$
  2a^6 + 2b^6 + 2c^6 + a^3 b^3 + b^3 c^3 + c^3 a^3 \geq 3ab^5 + 3bc^5 + 3ca^5.
$$

Now by AM-GM, we have
$$
  a^6 + a^6 + c^3 a^3 \geq 3ca^5
$$
and similarly
$$
  2b^6 + a^3 b^3 \geq 3ab^3 \quad\text{ and }\quad 2c^6 + b^3 c^3 \geq 3bc^5,
$$
and adding these together gives us the desired inequality.

Comment: (+1) though the substitution was unnecessary, see my answer.

Comment: I think that the substitution is never truly necessary since you can take the proof with the substitution and undo the substitution on every step, but sometimes the substitution makes the algebra slightly more pleasant, or makes it easier to spot that some inequality can be applied.

Comment: (+1) Although the fraction substitution was very interesting, I still can't see how your transformed the inequality. Maybe because it's getting late over here and I need sleep.

Comment: $\frac{x^5}{x^2 + 1}$ becomes $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{a^5}{b^5}}{\frac{a^2}{b^2} + 1}$. Then multiply then numerator and denominator by $b^5$ to get $\displaystyle \frac{a^5}{\frac{a^2 b^5}{b^2} + b^5} = \frac{a^5}{a^2 b^3 + b^5}$. In the next line before applying Cauchy I then multiply then numerator and denominator by $a$.

Answer (score 1):

No tricks requires, just standard techniques.

Lemma: Apply Jensen's to show that

> If $ \frac{ x+y+z}{3}  = A $, then $\sum \frac{ x^5 } { x^2 + 1 } \geq 3 \frac{ A^5}{A^2 + 1 }$.

Proof: Work through the [tedious verification that $f''(x) = \frac{ 2x^3 (3x^4 + 9x^2 + 10 } { (x^2+1)^3 }  \geq 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=second+derivative+of+x%5E5%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+1%29).

Corollary:
The condition $ xyz=1 $ tells us that $ x+y+z \geq 3$. Hence,
$$ \sum \frac{ x^5 }{ x^2 + 1 } \geq 3 \frac{ A^ 5 } { A^2 + 1 } \geq \frac{3}{2}.$$

Equality holds iff $ A = 1, x=y=z = 1$.

Comment: You seem to be missing a bracket in the text of the link

Answer (score 1):

From the hypothesis, we can rewrite the first inequality as:
$$\frac{x^4}{x+yz}+\frac{y^4}{y+zx}+\frac{z^4}{z+xy} \ge \frac{3}{2}$$
By applying Titu's lemma, we have:
$$\frac{x^4}{x+yz}+\frac{y^4}{y+zx}+\frac{z^4}{z+xy} \ge \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{x+y+z+xy+yz+xz} \ge \frac{\dfrac{1}{9}(x+y+z)^4}{x+y+z+\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)^2}$$
Let $x+y+z=t$.Thus, we just need to prove:
$$\frac{t^4}{9t+3t^2} \ge \frac{3}{2}$$
Which is equivalent to:
$$t(t-3)(2t^2+6t+9) \ge 0$$
It's obvious since $t=a+b+c \ge 3(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3$